# Xaml/Xamarin - HorizontalOptions not being followed by second child of container

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is how my layout looks currently: [image: Screencap]

My intention is to have that Pending text in one line without it being character-wrapped onto two lines.

My understanding of XAML was that I could do this by setting the yellow text label to something like `HorizontalOptions="Start"` with my text in green having `EndAndExpand` or `FillAndExpand` so that it's container would grow to meet it's width needs.

As you can tell by the screenshot that hasn't worked out very well for me and I've spent hours trying every variation on this I can think of and I have gotten absolutely nowhere.

The only way I can get the text to be shown on one line is to manually set the width, which is useless since it will be dynamic and can be short or long. Secondly, I could reduce the amount of yellow text (which does allow the green text to appear on one line), which is also useless since the titles will have roughly that length to them.

I've also tried changing the `LineBreakMode` but that does nothing for layout and the characters that would normally be wrapped are instead not displayed.

E: This is my XAML too:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="jamespaulprofileicon.jpg" 
           HeightRequest="70" 
           WidthRequest="70" 
           Margin="10,15,10,0" 
           HorizontalOptions="Start" 
           VerticalOptions="Start"/>

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                     BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Text="This is a test title with a normal amount of text " 
                   Font="17" 
                   TextColor="Black" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                   Margin="0" 
                   BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Green" 
                   CornerRadius="14" 
                   Padding="0,0,0,0" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HasShadow="False">
                <Label Text="Pending" 
                       Font="12" 
                       TextColor="White"  
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Absolutely any and all help would be appreciated on this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try replacing your `StackLayout` with a `Grid` and then adjust your frame accordingly.

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="This is a test title with a normal amount of text " Font="17" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Green" CornerRadius="14" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" HasShadow="False">
        <Label Text="Pending" Font="12" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

If you do that though you might also want to try consolidating all your views on your `Page` to use that one grid instead of having extra nested stackLayouts like you currently have.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working with Grids. Do you know what was wrong with the initial stacklayout design I had though?

Comment: StackLayouts can do some really weird things like that when one of its children doesn't have enough available space. Personally, I tend to use grids most of the time unless it's a pretty simple layout that I can get away with only 1 StackLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms provide another `Layout` options as `Grid`, for example, and I think this one can be more accurate to what you 're trying to achieve.

The problem you're facing is the `StackLayout` tries to adjust itself and its children view to obey their position constraints inside the current viewport that the screen provides, but this gets weird when the inner view requires more space than is available. *Probably if you turn you emulator to landscape mode the layout you've wrote with stacklayouts should look like you're expecting (this way it'll get space enough)*.

On the other hand, the grid's rows and columns constraints are more flexible and fair to understand this kind of layout.

If I'd understood what you want, the layout should look like this:

[image: [Image sample]]

As you can see, it's a grid with 1 row and 3 columns. About the columns, they are:
- First, fixed width
- Second, dynamically occupy all available space
- Third, the width should fit its content width

**This is how you can express it with `Grid`:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" 
           Source="jamespaulprofileicon.jpg" 
           HeightRequest="70"
           Margin="10,15,10,0" 
           HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
           VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
           Text="This is a test title with a normal amount of text " 
           Font="17" 
           TextColor="Black"
           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
           BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
    <Frame Grid.Column="2" 
           BackgroundColor="Green" 
           CornerRadius="14" 
           VerticalOptions="Start" 
           HasShadow="False">
        <Label Text="Pending" 
               Font="12" 
               TextColor="White"  
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

I encourage you to take a look at the [xamarin.forms layout docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts) for more information.

I hope it helps (and sorry for the poor English).